# Evaluate the probability density of Gaussian distribution on a square grid

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-random

I need to generate an image mask of dimensions m × n corresponding to a two-dimensional Gaussian with center at µ = (i, j) and σ^2 = 25, using NumPy.

After searching on the net, I found [this documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html#numpy.random.multivariate_normal) which looks promising. However, there are a few problems:

- Generated matrix is not a mask (binary)
- Covariance (σ^2) is given as a matrix and not as an integer

Perhaps using some mathematical properties, this could be transformed into what I want, but I can't see it because I'm not really good at maths.

Comment: The output of a Gaussian function is real numbers, not booleans. Are you sure you want booleans? Are you trying to *window* the image with a Gaussian?

Comment: `numpy.random.multivariate_normal` will give you a list of samples from a distribution which are not ordered on a grid like a matrix. Also, is the covariance is a "scalar" you can weite is as `sigma^2 * numpy.eye(D)` where D is the dimention.

Comment: Yes... I need a binary matrix (mask) following a gaussian distribution. I'm trying to compute M from equation (1) from [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.00138.pdf)

Comment: You misunderstood their notation: (0,1) means the interval of real numbers between 0 and 1. Not {0, 1} which would be the two-element set with elements 0, 1. Their M is just the Gaussian pdf computed on a square grid.

Comment: ok @CrazyIvan I got it... but I still don't know how to compute it with numpy :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.random.multivariate_normal` will give you *samples* drawn from a multivariate Gaussian distribution with mean 0 and variance 1. You want to compute the *probability density function* (PDF) for this distribution, not draw samples from it.

The easiest thing to do is use the `scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.pdf` function, as follows:

```
m, n = 100, 100
lims = (-3, 3) # support of the PDF
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(*lims, m), np.linspace(*lims, n))
points = np.stack((xx, yy), axis=-1)
mean = (1, 2) # Whatever your (i, j) is
covariance = 25.0
pdf = scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.pdf(points, mean, covariance)
```

`pdf` now gives the height of the Gaussian function at each of the points in the plane between -3 and 3 on both the x- and y-axes.

You can apply this window to whatever images you want, by just doing `image * pdf`.

EDITS:

Thanks to CrazyIvan for pointing out the `pdf` function takes a grid of points directly. Also note that `np.linspace(*lims, m)` uses Python3-specific tuple-unpacking. If you have an older version, just do `np.linspace(lims[0], lims[1], m)`.

Comment: I had the issue with  "only keyword arguments after * expression" with python 2, no problem with 3.

However pdf end up being an array of shape (10000,). Shouldn't it be a matrix of shape (m,n)? Or i need just to reshape pdf to get my M matrix?

Comment: @RodrigoLaguna Did you use the edited version of my answer? `points` should have shape `(m, n, 2)`, which will give `pdf` a shape of `(m, n)`. No reshaping should be required.

Comment: Thank you @bnaecker
I tried it with ipython, on python 2.7 and worked perfectly.
Some notes: I had to import scipy as follows `from scipy import stats` since importing directly `scipy` throws an error.

I would like to read more about this pdf to understand how does it work, end also understand what role does `lims` variable plays on your code. 

Thank you again!

Comment: @RodrigoLaguna Not sure why `import scipy` fails. Could you a problem with your installation. The PDF function is pretty straightforward: it just evaluates [this function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Density_function) at the points you pass. That might look complicated, but it's just `exp((x-mean)**2) / sqrt(2 * variance)`, extended to multiple dimensions.

Comment: @RodrigoLaguna It is the limits of the support of the PDF. The support is the range of values over which the PDF is computed. So the grid covers `[-3, 3]` in both x and y.